# Select box option list overlaping on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

[image]

When click on select box then mouse over on menu

Select box option list overlaping on menu.

I have already used z-index property but its not working.

Select box hide but not option list. You can use any ready made menu and put select box at near the place on menu option list always display

CSS :

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#navigation li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}

#navigation li a {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
}

#navigation li:hover .main {
    color: #ee4e1d;
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav {
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

#navigation li:hover .sub-nav-wrapper {
    display: block;
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav li:first-child {
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1.0);

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
}

#navigation li .sub-nav-wrapper .sub-nav li:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
}

/*****END DROPDOWN*****/


HTML :
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="main">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="main">Portfolio</a>
        <div class="sub-nav-wrapper"><ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" class="main">Services</a>
        <div class="sub-nav-wrapper"><ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Content Writing</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#" class="main">Technology</a>
        <div class="sub-nav-wrapper"><ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Wordpress</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oracle</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    </li>

</ul>

<!-----END NAVIGATION----->
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:900px;text-align:center;">
<select name="search_type" id="search-type" >
                <option value="Data2">Data1</option>
                <option value="Data1">Data1</option>
                </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: It ll be better if you add code because by seeing image we can't assume your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. cannot publish code but its simple menu and I have already used z-index and position relative but not working. Select box hide but not option list

Answer (score 0):

try adding : 
`"position:relative"` 
to the parent div of menu.

Comment: At least show some sample code with sample text.. we cant imagine your structure. Where did you applied that position?

Answer (score 0):

try using a higher value for z-index. It may work. As said by Era u can also use position relative, but if you are using many similar kind of things, every time you should have to change the positions.